# ADF Calendar, events without model

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to code in ADF a calendar to use in WCP. Typically, this component receive as value a VO. In my project I don't have a VO because is a customization of an asset.

How can I add events to the calendar without a Model Class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use af:Calendar without Model. 
From my own experience af:Calendar component is really slow and hardly customizable, if you really want to write calendar using ADF you can write your own component and use object-oriented way: create classes in your ViewController and use them in beans.

This anwser isn't really helpful, but I had the same problem few monthes ago. Oracle support didn't help us when af:Calendar component start lagging with ~500 activities in a month.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Advanced → Binding
2. Create a binding for that component.
3. You will get java class of that component.
4. Use that java methods to do your customizations.